# the curl link is not sent

Tags: php, curl

Create Message Function not working
this is form execute
That need to go to that sms api link
and now its not getting called please help me to fix this

```html
<?php 

include_once('inc/class.simple_mail.php');
include_once('inc/gump.class.php');

include_once('mail-config.php');



// Check Data
$isValid = GUMP::is_valid($_POST, array(
 'first-name' => 'required',
 'last-name' => 'required',
 'phone-number' => 'required',
 'email-address' => 'required|valid_email',
 'address' => 'required',
 'city' => 'required',
 'zip-code' => 'required',
 ));
 

if($isValid === true) {

 // Submit Mail
 $mail = new SimpleMail();
 $mail->setTo(YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS, YOUR_COMPANY_NAME)
 ->setSubject('New car rental request')
 ->setFrom(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email-address']), htmlspecialchars($_POST['first-name'].' '.$_POST['last-name']))
 ->addGenericHeader('X-Mailer', 'PHP/' . phpversion())
 ->addGenericHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset="utf-8"')
 ->setMessage(createMessage($_POST))
 ->setWrap(100);

 $mail->send();


 // Submit Client Mail
 $mailClient = new SimpleMail();
 $mailClient->setTo(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email-address']), htmlspecialchars($_POST['first-name'].' '.$_POST['last-name']))
 ->setSubject('Youre car rental request at '.YOUR_COMPANY_NAME)
 ->setFrom(YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS, YOUR_COMPANY_NAME)
 ->addGenericHeader('X-Mailer', 'PHP/' . phpversion())
 ->addGenericHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset="utf-8"')
 ->setMessage(createClientMessage($_POST))
 ->setWrap(100);

 $mailClient->send();

 $result = array(
  'result' => 'success', 
  'msg' => array('Success! Your contact request has been send.')
  );

 echo json_encode($result);

} else {
 $result = array(
  'result' => 'error', 
  'msg' => $isValid
  );

 echo json_encode($result);
}


function createMessage($formData)
{
      $message   = "$_POST['first-name']. Booked a Tata Innova From Website";
      $user="demo";//don't change this thing
      $password = "demopass";//don't change this thing
      $from      = "NANDHI";   // //don't change this thing - Sender ID
      $to        = "9566376463"";   // Ph# txt message is sent to
      
      
      $fields = array( ///URL Details that you are sending... 
       'user'  =>  urlencode($user),
       'password' =>  urlencode($password),
       'phone'    => urlencode($to),
       'text'     => urlencode($message),
       'type'  =>  't',
       'senderid' => urlencode($from),
         );
      
      foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
      rtrim($fields_string,'&');
      $url       = 'http://login.redsms.in/API/SendMessage.ashx?'.$fields_string;
      $ch = curl_init();
      
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

      $result = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
}

function createClientMessage($formData)
{
 $body  =  "Hello ".htmlspecialchars($formData['first-name'])." ".htmlspecialchars($formData['last-name'])."<br><br>";
 $body .= "We appreciate your interest in our offer. Your request has been successfully forwarded to us.<br>";
 $body .= "We will deal with it immediately and contact you as soon as possible in contact with you.<br><br>";
 $body .= "For further questions we are happy to help! <br><br>";
 $body .= "Best regards<br>".YOUR_COMPANY_NAME;


 return $body;
}






















// $mail = new SimpleMail();
// $mail->setTo('mail@themeinjection.com', 'Your Email')
// ->setSubject('Test Message')
// ->setFrom('no-reply@domain.com', 'Domain.com')
// ->addMailHeader('Reply-To', 'no-reply@domain.com', 'Domain.com')
// ->addMailHeader('Cc', 'bill@example.com', 'Bill Gates')
// ->addMailHeader('Bcc', 'steve@example.com', 'Steve Jobs')
// ->addGenericHeader('X-Mailer', 'PHP/' . phpversion())
// ->addGenericHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset="utf-8"')
// ->setMessage('<strong>This is a test message.</strong>')
// ->setWrap(100);
//$send = $mail->send();
//echo ($send) ? 'Email sent successfully' : 'Could not send email';


//echo json_encode(array('data' => 'test data'));

/* AJAX check  */
// if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
//  echo json_encode(array('data' => 'test data'));
// }
// else
// {
//  echo 'no ajax';
// }
```

code over heredgdgdgdg
code over heredgdgdgdgcode over heredgdgdgdgcode over heredgdgdgdgcode over heredgdgdgdgcode over heredgdgdgdgcode over heredgdgdgdgcode over heredgdgdgdgcode over heredgdgdgdgcode over heredgdgdgdgcode over heredgdgdgdgcode over heredgdgdgdgcode over heredgdgdgdgcode over heredgdgdgdgcode over heredgdgdgdgcode over heredgdgdgdgcode over heredgdgdgdgcode over heredgdgdgdg

Comment: Please make sure that CURL is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the createMessage function. I have corrected the two lines $message   = $_POST['first-name'] and $to        = "9566376463";   // Ph# txt message is sent to

```html
<?php 

include_once('inc/class.simple_mail.php');
include_once('inc/gump.class.php');

include_once('mail-config.php');



// Check Data
$isValid = GUMP::is_valid($_POST, array(
 'first-name' => 'required',
 'last-name' => 'required',
 'phone-number' => 'required',
 'email-address' => 'required|valid_email',
 'address' => 'required',
 'city' => 'required',
 'zip-code' => 'required',
 ));
 

if($isValid === true) {

 // Submit Mail
 $mail = new SimpleMail();
 $mail->setTo(YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS, YOUR_COMPANY_NAME)
 ->setSubject('New car rental request')
 ->setFrom(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email-address']), htmlspecialchars($_POST['first-name'].' '.$_POST['last-name']))
 ->addGenericHeader('X-Mailer', 'PHP/' . phpversion())
 ->addGenericHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset="utf-8"')
 ->setMessage(createMessage($_POST))
 ->setWrap(100);

 $mail->send();


 // Submit Client Mail
 $mailClient = new SimpleMail();
 $mailClient->setTo(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email-address']), htmlspecialchars($_POST['first-name'].' '.$_POST['last-name']))
 ->setSubject('Youre car rental request at '.YOUR_COMPANY_NAME)
 ->setFrom(YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS, YOUR_COMPANY_NAME)
 ->addGenericHeader('X-Mailer', 'PHP/' . phpversion())
 ->addGenericHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset="utf-8"')
 ->setMessage(createClientMessage($_POST))
 ->setWrap(100);

 $mailClient->send();

 $result = array(
  'result' => 'success', 
  'msg' => array('Success! Your contact request has been send.')
  );

 echo json_encode($result);

} else {
 $result = array(
  'result' => 'error', 
  'msg' => $isValid
  );

 echo json_encode($result);
}


function createMessage($formData)
{
                    $message = $_POST['first-name']. " Booked a ".$_POST['selected-car']."Contact :".$_POST['phone-number'];
     //$message   = $_POST['first-name']. "Booked a Tata Innova From Website"; //Corrected string
     $user="demo";//don't change this thing
     $password = "demopass";//don't change this thing
     $from      = "NANDHI";   // //don't change this thing - Sender ID
     $to        = "9566376463";   // Ph# txt message is sent to //Corrected double quote
     
     
     $fields = array( ///URL Details that you are sending... 
      'user'  =>  urlencode($user),
      'password' =>  urlencode($password),
      'phone'    => urlencode($to),
      'text'     => urlencode($message),
      'type'  =>  't',
      'senderid' => urlencode($from),
        );
     
     foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
     rtrim($fields_string,'&');
     $url       = 'http://login.redsms.in/API/SendMessage.ashx?'.$fields_string;
     $ch = curl_init();
     
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

     $result = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
}

function createClientMessage($formData)
{
 $body  =  "Hello ".htmlspecialchars($formData['first-name'])." ".htmlspecialchars($formData['last-name'])."<br><br>";
 $body .= "We appreciate your interest in our offer. Your request has been successfully forwarded to us.<br>";
 $body .= "We will deal with it immediately and contact you as soon as possible in contact with you.<br><br>";
 $body .= "For further questions we are happy to help! <br><br>";
 $body .= "Best regards<br>".YOUR_COMPANY_NAME;


 return $body;
}






















// $mail = new SimpleMail();
// $mail->setTo('mail@themeinjection.com', 'Your Email')
// ->setSubject('Test Message')
// ->setFrom('no-reply@domain.com', 'Domain.com')
// ->addMailHeader('Reply-To', 'no-reply@domain.com', 'Domain.com')
// ->addMailHeader('Cc', 'bill@example.com', 'Bill Gates')
// ->addMailHeader('Bcc', 'steve@example.com', 'Steve Jobs')
// ->addGenericHeader('X-Mailer', 'PHP/' . phpversion())
// ->addGenericHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset="utf-8"')
// ->setMessage('<strong>This is a test message.</strong>')
// ->setWrap(100);
//$send = $mail->send();
//echo ($send) ? 'Email sent successfully' : 'Could not send email';


//echo json_encode(array('data' => 'test data'));

/* AJAX check  */
// if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
//  echo json_encode(array('data' => 'test data'));
// }
// else
// {
//  echo 'no ajax';
// }
```

Comment: How to use two code like $message   = $_POST['first-name']. " Booked a "$_POST['selected-car']."Contact :"$_POST['phone-number'].; //Corrected string